# Why are address are not consecutive when allocating single bytes?

Tags: c, unix, alignment, malloc

I am dynamically allocating memory as follows:

```
char* heap_start1 = (char*) malloc(1);
char* heap_start2 = (char*) malloc(1);
```

When I do printf as follows surprisingly the addresses are not consecutives.

```
printf("%p, %p \n",heap_start1,heap_start2);
```

Result:

```
   0x8246008, 0x8246018
```

As you can see there is a 15 bytes of extra memory that are left defragmented. It's definitely not because of word alignment. Any idea behind this peculiar alignment?

Thanks in advance!

I am using gcc in linux if that matters.

Comment: In addition: Malloc needs some space for its own bookkeeping. This often "N-bytes" (for some small N) *before* the returned pointer.

Comment: The spec requires `malloc()` to return a pointer suitably aligned for any object with a fundamental alignment requirement.  That's almost certainly greater than 1.

Comment: Another note - you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.

Comment: "surprisingly the addresses are not consecutive" -- On the contrary, it would be extremely surprising if they were. "It's definitely not because of word alignment" -- Depends on what you mean by a "word". Do read the malloc documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

glibc's `malloc`, for small memory allocations less than 16 bytes, simply allocates the memory as 16 bytes. This is to prevent external fragmentation upon the freeing of this memory, where blocks of free memory are too small to be used in the general case to fulfill new `malloc` operations.

A block allocated by `malloc` must also be large enough to store the data required to track it in the data structure which stores free blocks.

This behaviour, while increasing internal fragmentation, decreases overall fragmentation throughout the system.

**Source:**
http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/malloc/malloc.c
(Read line 108 in particular)

```
/*
...
Minimum allocated size: 4-byte ptrs:  16 bytes    (including 4 overhead)
...
*/
```

Furthermore, all addresses returned by the `malloc` call in glibc are aligned to: `2 * sizeof(size_t)` bytes. Which is 64 bits for 32-bit systems (such as yours) and 128 bits for 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 4):

At least three possible reasons:

- `malloc` needs to produce memory that is suitably-aligned for all primitive types.  <s>Data for SSE instructions needs to be 128-bit aligned.  (There may also be other 128-bit primitive types that your platform supports that don't occur to me at the moment.)</s>
- A typical implementation of `malloc` involves "over-allocation" in order to store bookkeeping information for a speedy `free`.  Not sure if GCC on Linux does this.
- It may be allocating [*guard bytes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_byte) in order to allow detection of buffer overflows and so on.

Comment: But then how come you can still perform operations on members of an array which are not 128-bit aligned? I think there's more to this than just memory alignment.

Comment: @AndrewDunn: You're talking about SSE operations?  I think SSE4 added support for unaligned accesses (although this isn't my area of expertise!).

Comment: As seen in the original question, `0x8246008` is not aligned to 128-bits anyway.

Comment: I think it's just 64-bit aligned for `long long` types.  The OP is using a 32-bit machine, based on the length of those `%p` prints.

Comment: All SSE generations ALLOW unaligned access for most instructions, but at a speed penalty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate consecutive addresses you should allocate them on the same malloc

```
char *heap_start1, *heap_start2;
heap_start1 = (char*) malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
heap_start2 = heap_start1 + 1;
```

Comment: It is just a better coding practice, you can`t suppose that the size of char is 1... in the heap_start2 assignment you may use +1 because it is a pointer arithmetic so it is going to add the size of char automatically.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.  Always.  It's in the definition of the language.  If you want better coding practice, I could *maybe* get behind `malloc(2 * sizeof *heap_start)`, in case you were to change the type later.

Comment: What? No, that would allocate space for two *pointers*.  You want two `char`s, right? I did miss a `1` there - sorry:  `malloc(2 * sizeof *heap_start1)`.

Comment: Never assume the size of any datatype in C, especially if you are coding for reuse. You can never tell what architecture your code may be compiled for.

Comment: @Andrew, `sizeof(char)` is not going to change.  I'm all for being careful and writing reusable code, but adding unnecessary clutter doesn't really count.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` might be consistently equal to `1` on a variety of architectures, but the standard only states that `char` must be at minimum 8-bits wide, and that it must be the size of the smallest possible addressable block of data, which in some CPUs may be more than 1 byte. Old 16-bit processors come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` guarantees that returned memory is properly aligned for any basic type. Moreover, memory block could be padded with some guard bytes to check for memory corruption, it depends on settings.