# Why the Memory locations for two variables which is allocated dynamically are not consecutive?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I use two variables in which memory is allocated dynamically, and I print the memory locations, but they are not consecutive.  Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("\n a=%p \t b=%p  \n",a,b);
}
```

The answers I get (in Linux) are

1st time:

```
 a=0x20a0010     b=0x20a0030
```

2nd time:

```
 a=0x657010      b=0x657030
```

3rd time:

```
 a=0x139e010     b=0x139e030
```

Why is the exact difference between the memory locations of `a` and `b` variables the way it is in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd times?

Is this related to paging memory?

My processor is 64 bit.

Comment: Does it matter? If you need consecutive addresses, you should be using an array.

Comment: While this is misguided, it is an interesting question. With nothing else, you might expect the memory locations to be consecutive

Comment: Your addresses are `32` bytes apart. If they were consecutive, you'd expect them to be `4` bytes apart (assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4`, which it seems to usually be)

Comment: `malloc()` allocates more than just the number of bytes requested, because it has to store extra tracking information in the memory block so `free()` knows how to release the memory correctly.  Think about it.  You are allocating `sizeof(int)` bytes.  How do you think `free()` knows to release `sizeof(int)` bytes if you don't pass `sizeof(int)` as a parameter to it?  That info has to be stored somewhere, and the only thing passed to `free()` is the memory pointer, so the info has to be in the memory block itself.

Comment: With what @RemyLebeau said, it's also true that it can be more efficient to have `malloc()` only allocate blocks of a certain size or higher; if you request a smaller size, it can be promoted to this larger size

Comment: Thank you @ Justin .. you understood my question at proper..   thank you @remy lebeau ... your answer may be correct... You are telling that instead of allocating actually 4 bytes of memory for int ...it is allocating 32 bytes for tracking of some info to allow for free() and something else...  that means it is using extra 24 bytes of memory for tracking .. that means for one integer it will take 32 bytes of memory ... Am I correct to your point...

Comment: [Why are address are not consecutive when allocating single bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14616145/608639), [Why do successive calls to new\[\] not allocate contiguous memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25677458/608639), etc.

Comment: oh!!!! Thank you @jww

Answer (score 7):

The gap between two consecutive allocations is not related to paging. Your allocations are so small that they reside in the data segment. Libc handles these internally - the space outside your `sizeof int` bytes generally contains pointers to the previous and the next block of data and the size of allocation - after all `free` will just get a pointer and it will need to figure out how much memory it is to deallocate.

Additionally both of these pointers are aligned to 16-byte boundary. [C11 7.22.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3) says that

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is **suitably aligned** so that it may be assigned to **a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement** and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

Thus even though you're using them for `int` the C standard requires that the pointer returned be aligned for any data type - which on your implementation is 16 bytes.

If however you allocate an object that is very *large*, glibc will map entire pages using `mmap` instead. Then the alignment (on my 64-bit computer) is exactly 16 bytes from the start of a 4K page:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *a = malloc(12345678);
    int *b = malloc(12345678);
    printf("\n a=%p \t b=%p  \n",a,b);
}
```

when run

```
% ./a.out  

 a=0x7fb65e7b7010     b=0x7fb65dbf0010
```

One can see the `mmap` calls with `strace ./a.out` - there among other system calls there are

```
mmap(NULL, 12349440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb65e7b7000
mmap(NULL, 12349440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb65dbf0000
```

---

As for why the addresses keep changing from one execution to another - this is due to [address space layout randomization, or ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) - a security mechanism which makes it harder for evil crackers to **predictably** exploit *undefined behaviour* in your code.

---

P.S. If you really need to dynamically allocate space for 2 `int`s at consecutive addresses, allocate an array.

Comment: So why are the pointer values different each time?

Comment: @EJP added that too

Comment: thank you @ antti haapala .. But I don't want that memory to be contiguous.. why it is not contiguous is my question..   as well as i have mentioned my memory locations for 1st time,2nd time and 3rd time of my execution of program.. if you observe that the locations and the difference b/w the memory locations alloctaed.. if found something ambiguous ...

Comment: well, I've answered that above too

Comment: Thank you @ antti haapala.. I didn't read properly...that's my mistake.. thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 2):

The operating system handles memory allocation, and there is no guarantee that this memory is contiguous when dynamically allocating two consecutive variables. I should also mention that this is the outcome of a defense mechanism known as [ASLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605222/what-is-address-space-layout-randomization). ASLR defends against buffer overflows by randomizing the location of a process during its execution, this may include the [stack, heap, and libraries](https://www.howtogeek.com/278056/what-is-aslr-and-how-does-it-keep-your-computer-secure/). This is why you notice these addresses changing. By the standard, you're only guaranteed the following.

> ISO C11 7.22.3.4 Malloc
>
> 1) **Synopsis**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void* malloc(size_t size);
```

> 2) **Description** 
>   The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.
>
> 3) **Return**
>   The malloc function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space.

Comment: *"The operating system handles memory allocation"* - Not necessarily true. Once memory is acquired, the runtime may provide allocations if the memory was previously free'd. Also see [Will malloc implementations return free-ed memory back to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215259/608639)

Answer (score 0):

As note at [GNU Examples of malloc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Examples.html)

> Note that the memory located after the end of the block is likely to
>   be in use for something else; perhaps a block already allocated by
>   another call to malloc.

This actually means that, for each call to `malloc` the OS, depending on its memory management algorithm, finds the most appropriate / proper / suitable / efficient free space for the caller.

For example:

```
void* p_1 = malloc(4);
void* p_2 = malloc(4);

[oooo][xxxx][oooo][oooo]
^           ^
p_1         p_2
```